# how can we compute inverse of tf.variable()

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

In tensorflow, we may use `tf.get_variable()` to set a variable, for example, use it to define the covariance `Sigma` of a Gaussian distribution.

I want to know how to compute the inverse of `Sigma` and how can I use this inverse in building a tensorflow graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [tf.matrix_inverse](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/matrix_inverse) which does exactly that.